# Good praxis and performance benefit using a public reference to a private variable

Tags: c++, class, reference, public, member

Is a public reference to a private class member allowed? I know, following code will compile and as I was using it, it worked in 99% cases. The problem is, I really meet some configuration, where the const reference to a private variable returned wrong data, even using with POD. So, is there some general problem with it - wrong syntax, or some other case, where it can fail? Is there any performance benefit using const reference against using Get() method? Please see the comments in the following code... How is this seen in terms of 'good coding style'? What about 'good praxis'?

Own research: well, there is probably no performance benefit to prefer const reference instead of Get() method when using simple data type. To return just a reference might be usefull when using a large struct. Const ref might break good OOP rules (Encapsulation and Lifetime).

But again, the basic question: is there any reason why should "const int &Width" fail, even if using on a valid (existing) instance? What about exporting class CTest from a dll? Thx

```
class CTest
{
public:
  // public reference to a private variable - is this allowed? What about standards, what about 'good coding'?
  const int & Width; // read only property

  // Is there some performance penalty for GetWidth1() compared to previous reference Width?
  /*(inline)*/ int GetWidth1() const { return _width; } 

  // some performance benefit or disadvantage writting GetWidth2 rather than GetWidth1()?
  const int & GetWidth2() const { return _width; } 

  CTest(int width):
    Width(_width), // initialize public reference to a private variable - is this correct?
    _width(width)  // initialize member variable
  {}
private:
  int _width;
};

int main()
{
  CTest cTest(10);
  CTest * pTest = new CTest(10);

  int width1 = cTest.Width; // is this possible? Is there some reason (not) to use such a construction?
  int width2 = pTest->Width;
  int width3 = pTest->GetWidth1(); // of course, correct. But is there some performance penalty compared to pTest->Width?

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you demonstrate that 1% that fails?

Comment: Sorry, actually not, it's couple of weeks ago and I don't have access to that code version anymore. May be, missing copy constructor was the issue. That 1% would be 'using copy constructor' in 1% cases...

Answer (score 2):

> Is a public reference to a private class member allowed?

Yes, there's nothing inherently wrong with that. If you've seen cases of it "returning wrong data", that implies that something else has gone wrong - perhaps memory corruption, or accessing the reference before the data member has been initialised, or using a dangling reference after its target has been destroyed.

The biggest issue is that references are not assignable, and so neither is any class that contains one.

> Is there any performance benefit using const reference against using Get() method?

I would expect a benefit from using an inline function rather than a reference. There is nothing to store in the class instance, and no need for any run-time indirection - it should be as efficient as accessing the data member directly. For that reason, I would recommend you don't use a reference member.

> How is this seen in terms of 'good coding style'? What about 'good praxis'?

In general, access to data members may be an indication that the class isn't very well encapsulated. Good (object-oriented) practice usually specifies an interface in terms of what it does, not what data it works with. But that's very general advice. Sometimes the best design does call for access to data; but for efficiency, you should allow that through either public data members or inline accessor functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly allowed to expose a reference to private data. It also works fine when used correct. Note, however, that it will probably make things slower than an inline function providing access to the variable because the compiler in most cases actually stores a pointer or reference to represent the reference. The cost of using storing the indirection is increased object size and an extra dereference. When you say it fails, I'd suspect that you didn't correctly initialize the reference, e.g., upon using the copy constructor.

BTW, `main()` always returns `int` (although the return statement can be left off).

Comment: Ok, I see. But what would happen, if one defines CTest class in an interface of some dll? Will 'inline' GetWidth1() expand to some code and what happens with a public const reference in that case? Does it impact performance?